# Android EditText check if text match requested

Tags: java, android, match, editview

I have a `EditText` in my application that i need to check if the text is like,

##-##-##

the "#" can be letters or numbers in groups of 2,
how can i do that?

Comment: use regular expressions.

Comment: There is nothing like `EditView` in Android. Either `EditText` or `TextView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `regex`:-

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}";
System.out.println(str.matches(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the text that user entered and run a regular expression check on it.

[Here is a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)  for regular expressions in Java by Sun.

To get the text from the `EditText` field and convert it to string use the following:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_edit_field_id);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This check when the text is changed !

```
EditText etSearch this.etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_edittext);
etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatchControl());


private class TextWatchControl implements TextWatcher {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
             String test = etSearch.getText().toString();
            if (test.matches("[0-9]{2}-{1}[0-9]{2}-{1}[0-9]{2}""))
                 //true
            else
                 //false
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }


    }
```